# Moving Messages from Azure Queues to Database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-queues

I'm a newbie to Azure . So far been successful in developing a couple of functions that has been able to do the following

1. Trigger a function when a message arrives in Queue
2. Response received by function stored in a Queue

Now I know that I can read these messages from the queue with a programming SDK like with Python or .net . However I'd like to figure out if it is possible to do an ETL with Azure Data Factory to directly consume the messages instead of another function scanning through the queue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory doesn't support Queue(Storage queue or Service Bus Queue) as Data store for now. Please ref: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)

That means that we can not copy the Queue message directly with Data Factory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the link .Jus wanted to see if you have any other suggestions . Does it mean I'm left with another Queue trigger to load this to the Database ?

Comment: @RajeshRajamanir You're welcome. I just fount a tutorial:[Azure Functions Tutorial – Sql Database](https://www.sarmaad.com/2016/07/azure-functions-tutorial-sql-database/)  can help work with Azure SQL database. Some idea is that input from Queue and output to SQL. I think it may helps you.